# Variable in xpath in Python Selenium when calling Class and Function

Tags: python, selenium, class, variables, xpath

I have the following class:

```
class Sections(BasePage):

    CHOOSE_SECTION_SEL = (By.XPATH, "//*[@class='select2-result-label' and (text() = '" + state + "')]")

    def choose_section(self, state):
        self.click_on_element("choose section", self.CHOOSE_SECTION_SEL)
```

Then I want to call it like this so I can change the variable 'state' whatever I want but it is not working obviously:

```
section = Sections(driver=self.driver)
section.choose_section(state="CALENDAR")
```

I know I can do it like this and it is working:

```
class Sections:

    def section(self, state):
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='select2-result-label' and (text() = '" + state + "')]").click()

...

choose = Sections()
choose.section(state="CALENDAR")
```

However I have to do it like the first example. Any ideas what I have to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) notation to either of the following forms:

- Using *variable*:

  ```
  CHOOSE_SECTION_SEL = (By.XPATH, "//*[@class='select2-result-label' and text()='" + state + "']")
  ```
- Using `%s`

  ```
  CHOOSE_SECTION_SEL = (By.XPATH, "//*[@class='select2-result-label' and text()='%s']"% str(state))
  ```
- Using `{}`

  ```
  CHOOSE_SECTION_SEL = (By.XPATH, "//*[@class='select2-result-label' and text()='{}']".format(str(state)))
  ```

You can implement it like:

```
class Sections(BasePage):

    def choose_section(self, state):
        self.CHOOSE_SECTION_SEL = (By.XPATH, "//*[@class='select2-result-label' and (text() = '" + state + "')]")
        self.click_on_element("choose section", self.CHOOSE_SECTION_SEL)
```

Comment: Yes, I am using variable but I get the error message: ```CHOOSE_SECTION_SEL = (By.XPATH, "//*[@class='select2-result-label' and (text() = '" + state + "')]")
NameError: name 'state' is not defined```

Comment: @bbfl Checkout the answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: Thanks, it works but basically it is almost the same as my second example which also works. However is there a another way  ```CHOOSE_SECTION_SEL = (By.XPATH, "//*[@class='select2-result-label' and text()='" + state + "']")``` not be inside a function?

Comment: @bbfl Then the variable `state` needs to have global scope which you may like to avoid.

Comment: thanks a lot. Yes, it worked as you suggested and seems this is the most optimal way to do it!

Comment: @bbfl Feel free to visit [Selenium Chat Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) and help other users.